# How to open bitcoin source in IDE?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

After downloading bitcoin source from [github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) I'l try to open it in Netbeans for Mac. Please tell how to open all bitcoin project for run it with breakpoints in IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can recommend the Qt Creator IDE or Xcode on OSX. The later has (since Xcode 8) problems auto-completing C++.

If you use Qt Creators IDE, you can also debug the Qt objects natively.

In Qt Creator, do the following:

1. Install all dependencies
2. `git checkout https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin`
3. `./autogen.sh`
4. `./configure --enable-debug` (maybe more)
5. Then, create new project in Qt-Creator "import project from existing 
   source".
6. Go to project settings / run, select `src/qt/bitcoin-qt` (or `src/bitcoin`) as executable
7. Happy debugging / coding.

Comment: It's working but the breakpoints did not stop process. I want to see some variables and set breakpoint in line I need to view, but when I call in bitcoin-qt console command I need, the breakpoint did not work. Please help to set it correctly.

Comment: I make "Run". And think that it is not correct. So when I make "Debug run", the IDE ask me to specify "Debugger command" and I don't know where to find it. So I think here is my fault. Please help me.

Comment: Did you select the "Executable" in the "Project settings"?

Comment: Yes. I select the "Executable". But my IDE is Netbeans, not QT. So maby your example is not fully suitable for this.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonas said above, however ensure that `daemon` is NOT set to `1` in `bitcoin.conf` (or that it's passed as an argument on startup). If it is set, breakpoints will not be triggered (and in some cases can cause the whole program to crash).